# Javascript settimeinterval stops working in nodewebkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I have made a custom wamp server the code of nodewebkit just triggers processes/worker to launch the apache server which is working really fine. I had to run some cronjobs on pc the cronjob data comes from server when the app first starts. normally my cronjobs are running properly but after sometime the cronjobs just starts and never finishes and i have to restart the app. and then again for few days it keeps running.

```
function setLoops(i) {
var cron = cron_Jobs[i];
interval_array.push(window.setInterval(function() {
    genrate_log("started", cron.url);
    ajax_post(app_path + cron.url, function(data) {
        genrate_log("completed", cron.url);
    }, function(data) {
        genrate_log("error", cron.url);
    })
   }, cron.time))
 }

function clear_loops(i) {
  clearInterval(interval_array[i]);
 }

 function cron_jobs(run) {
    if (run == false) {
        for (var i = 0; i < interval_array.length; i++) {
          clear_loops(i);
       }
    }
  if (run == true) {
     for (var i = 0; i < cron_Jobs.length; i++) {
        setLoops(i);
     }
  }
 }
```

I thought it has something todo with log file when it become bigger than certain size it stops working. But I confirm that it has nothing todo with log file. I am pretty sure it has something todo with my algorithm or chromium. But not sure on that.

Comment: I'm not clear an what you mean when you say that "cronjobs just starts and never finishes".  Do you mean the function ajax_post never completes?  Or do you mean that the function cron_jobs is called but never returns?  If the latter, how do you know?

Comment: The ajax_call starts but never finishes.It sounds like the server is not responding correct ? But thats not the case. Node webkit /chromium browser is doing something wrong with those calls. I can run those calls through regular browser.

Comment: To me its something like thread overflow because we are using main thread to make calls again and again.

Comment: Yeah true, to solve this I am running commands in CMD instead of triggering the scripts from the main thread of node web kit. That seems to be working for a long time and reliably for me